# Swapping odd/even margin in Latex

Tags: latex, margin

I'm writing something that I would like to print in Latex and I'm using the `book` documentclass.

The standard behaviour is to consider odd pages (so the rear of a double sided paper) as the beginning of chapters and document too, I would like to swap them to be able to have correct margins: on an even page right margin is greater than left one, I need the opposite..

Does a simple snippet exist to achieve this thing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: consider tex.stackexchange.com (it is like stackoverflow, but for tex)

Comment: sorry, didn't know.. they spawn like mushrooms :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margins can be modified using the `geometry` package. The `inner` and `outer` arguments to this package control the margins you want to change:

```
\usepackage[a4paper,inner=3.5cm,outer=2.5cm]{geometry} % Or w/e
```